# c# how to enable button ontextchange without posting back

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, button, lightbox

so i have a lightbox in which pops up an aspx page with textboxes and two buttons (submit - disabled and cancel - enabled). I wanted to enable my submit button ontextchange. it works fine when opened separately (not as a lightbox) but when i let it run normally with the lightbox function everytime ontextchange gets triggered the whole page refreshes disabling the lightbox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="OnTextChanged_AttributesEdited" autopostback="true">


protected void OnTextChanged_AttributesEdited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnSubmit.Enabled = true;

}
```

now if i take out the "autopostback=true" it then will not trigger the the ontextchanged. was wondering if is it better if javascript will be the way to go for enabling the button or is there a way where i can prevent the postback when ontextchanged is triggered?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be a prime use for some jQuery in your application. Without posting back to the server for enabling / disabling a button, this would look a lot smoother, load faster and keep your current page state intact. An example might be as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#textBox1").change(function() {
        $("#btnSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
</script>
```

Just put the above script tag in your HTML, just before closing the `body` tag.

An even better solution, however, would be to assign a specific CSS class to all the textboxes that should inherit that behaviour. Assuming that you assign a CSS class called "someCssClass" to all those textboxes, your script would then look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("input.someCssClass").change(function() {
        $("#btnSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: hey thanks, i might have to read through it first as i have no idea on how to implement jquery.

Comment: It's quite easy. Just include a javascript reference to the jQuery library (also hosted by Google, but you can download it and host on your own domain), then include the script tag in my example...

Comment: Note that for `#textBox1` to work with ASP.NET controls, you'll need set the `ClientIDMode` to `Static` (ASP.NET 4.0 only though). Alternatively, you can use the following in your script block: `$("#<%= textBox1.ClientID%>")` as this will output the actual ID that is sent to the browser that the script will look for.

Comment: That won't be a problem if he isn't using master pages or the control isn't placed in a Web User Control. If it's the only control with that specific ID on the page, the client ID should match the server ID. Anyway, a better solution would be to do a selector based on class and assign the same CSS class to all textboxes that should inherit the behaviour.

Comment: hold up. so i will have issues if i'm using master pages? i mean, currently this page will be just plain aspx since it will be called from an aspx using a master page.

Comment: If you implement it as my second sample, you shouldn't have any issues at all. The jQuery selector is then dependent on a CSS class (irrespective of using master pages or not), instead of using a specific control ID (which is impacted by using master pages). So just stick to the .cssClass instead of #controlId and you should be fine. :)

Answer (score -1):

I'd use jQuery as mentioned by @FarligOpptrenden, but if you don't have it and just want plain javascript, this should work.

Input within your lightbox:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" onKeyUp="enableSubmitButton()" />
<input type="button" id="submitButton" value="Submit" />
<input type="button" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel" />
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function enableSubmitButton()
{
document.getElementById('submitButton').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('cancelButton').disabled = true;
}

</script>
```

You could also do your enabling/disabling buttons on load in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function () {

document.getElementById('submitButton').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('cancelButton').disabled = false;

}
</script>
```